# oozie scheduled job running more than the expected frequency

Tags: scheduler, oozie, jobs

[**oozie job data**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Yo0.jpg)

Hello,
i have scheduled a oozie coordinator job for a simple use case. all it does is, every 15 minutes, it creates a folder in a hdfs location. 
for the initial few runs, the job got submitted multiple times. however after few runs, it got back to the expected schedule of one job per 15 minute interval.
not sure why the initial runs were submitted multiple times. any thoughts on that? attached image shows the folder creation time.

oozie job schedule: frequency="0-59/15 * * * *"

Comment: Not sure how Oozie interprets `0-59/15` in CRON notation because, personally, I don't understand what it is supposed to do. The `0-59` part would mean "run once for every minute between 0 and 59" but then `/15` would mean "run again 15 min. after each initial run". Duh. I would have expected a syntax error raised at Coordinator submit time.

Comment: For what you want, use the legacy Oozie notation for "every 15 min. starting at Coordinator submission time"-- read the docs. Or maybe "at 4, 19, 34 and 49 of each hour" _(for instance, start is arbitrary)_ i.e. `4/15` which is equivalent to `4,19,34,49`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you want is `"0/15 * * * *"`. See the [Functional Spec](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a4.4.3._Cron_syntax_in_coordinator_frequency) for more information. Also consider that if your start time is earlier than the time at which you submit the coordinator, jobs occurring at a frequency in the past will also be submitted.